# Java BorderLayout Equal Size/Alignment

Tags: java, alignment, layout-manager

Using BorderLayout, how would I add two components that are equal in size and alignment and will resize as such.

As an example, I will use textarea1 and textarea2

Initially the panel is 200,100: textarea1 is at 0,0 and has a size of 100, 100 & textarea2 is at 100, 0 with a size of 100,100

The pane is resized to 300,300: textarea1 is at 0,0 and has a size of 150, 300 & textarea2 is at 150, 300

How can I do this with BorderLayout or any other layout manager if it is better suited to this type of activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with GridBagLayout. It allows the versatility of other layouts with the nice parts of a Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html). `GridLayout` ensures that all components have an equal size.